# Can’t seem to grab ID and pass it to inner function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’m trying to get the ID of an element on click, and pass it to the animate function which is the inner function.

I can easily get the ID but can’t seem to pass it to the inner function.

```
$("a").on("click",function() {
  var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id').substring(2);
  $('html, body').animate({
    // console.log(id);  NOT VISIBLE ?!
    scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: That will work fine.  This is called a closure.

Comment: Except that you don't even have an inner function; you just have meaningless syntax.

Comment: Hi SLaks, can't seem to pass it over , it doesn't recognize it?

Comment: Add a `console.log(id)` *before* the `.animate()` call to make sure it's been created. It's possible the element being clicked doesn't have an `id` attribute.

Comment: @Marin: Pass it _where_? Putting a statement in the middle of an object literal makes no sense.

Comment: Gotcha!  I tested it and it does seem to work! I feel intelligent - not.

Comment: Whats the purpose of the .substring(2)? if your Id is short (smaller than 2 chars) u always get "#" as id. Try removing the substring.

Comment: substring(2) because if i have it like  id="goMain"    then it goes to id="Main"